# MySql - Select and compute running AVG date by date

Tags: mysql

Ultra-noob question, I know, but since I'm not so skilled in MySql I looking for a little help.
I have the following 'my_table':

```
 date        |   value 
  -----------|----------
  01-05-2017 | 10
  02-05-2017 | 2
  03-05-2017 | 8
  04-05-2017 | 1
  05-05-2017 | 9
```

I would like to select the running average value date by date, as follows (desired result):

```
 date        |   value  | average
  -----------|----------|--------
  01-05-2017 | 10       | 10
  02-05-2017 | 2        | 6 (10+2/2)
  03-05-2017 | 8        | 6.66 (10+2+8/3)
  04-05-2017 | 1        | 5.25 (10+2+8+1/4)
  05-05-2017 | 9        | 6 (10+2+8+1+9/5)
```

Keeping in mind that 'my_table' has thousands of records (this is just an example).

I know that I can use AVG, i.e. as follows:

```
SELECT date, value, AVG(value) as average from my_table
```

And this returns the "global" average value.
I tried to use `GROUP BY date` but it returns the same exact value in the `average` column.

There is a simple and fast way to accomplish this in MySql? Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're trying to compute a running average?

Comment: Yes, thanks. And thank you for the head up. Got it.